# RabbitMQ how to stop reconnecting after AmqpIOException UnknownHostException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

for our integration-test profile we want to disable Spring's automatic reconnecting to fail fast.

```
Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq-invalid-host:5672]
Error creating consumer; retrying in 5000
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: rabbitmq-invalid-host
```

the following settings do not have any effect yet:

```
spring.rabbitmq.connection-timeout=1000
spring.rabbitmq.requested-heartbeat=1
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.missing-queues-fatal=true
spring.rabbitmq.listener.direct.retry.enabled=false
spring.rabbitmq.template.retry.enabled=false
```

any idea how to make amqp give up or even destroy the whole app-context?

full stacktrace:

```
2019-06-11 14:56:31.596  INFO 3025 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq-invalid-host:5672]
2019-06-11 14:56:31.698  INFO 3025 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq-invalid-host:5672]
2019-06-11 14:56:31.902  INFO 3025 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq-invalid-host:5672]
2019-06-11 14:56:32.305  INFO 3025 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq-invalid-host:5672]
2019-06-11 14:56:33.108  INFO 3025 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq-invalid-host:5672]
2019-06-11 14:56:34.709  INFO 3025 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq-invalid-host:5672]
2019-06-11 14:56:36.476  INFO 3025 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq-invalid-host:5672]
2019-06-11 14:56:36.477 ERROR 3025 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.l.DirectMessageListenerContainer : Error creating consumer; retrying in 5000

org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: rabbitmq-invalid-host
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.doConsumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:667) [spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.consumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:645) [spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.startConsumers(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:550) [spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.lambda$actualStart$1(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:410) [spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: rabbitmq-invalid-host
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:71) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:509) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:700) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.DirectMessageListenerContainer.doConsumeFromQueue(DirectMessageListenerContainer.java:663) [spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: rabbitmq-invalid-host
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.resolveIpAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:83) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.getAddresses(DnsRecordIpAddressResolver.java:73) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1098) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1054) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:994) ~[amqp-client-5.4.3.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:462) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2019-06-11 14:56:37.912  INFO 3025 --- [           main] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [rabbitmq-invalid-host:5672]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the exception in an event listener...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So56270299Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So56270299Application.class, args);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void events(ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
        if (event.getThrowable().getCause() instanceof UnknownHostException) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so56270299")
    public void listen(String in) {

    }

}
```

and

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=junk
```

and

```
2019-06-11 09:15:09.205  INFO 96620 --- [ntContainer#0-1] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Attempting to connect to: [junk:5672]
2019-06-11 09:15:09.212  INFO 96620 --- [           main] com.example.So56270299Application        : Started So56270299Application in 0.704 seconds (JVM running for 1.071)
ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent [reason=Consumer raised exception, attempting restart, fatal=false, throwable=org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.net.UnknownHostException: junk, container=SimpleMessageListenerContainer [concurrentConsumers=1, queueNames=[so56270299]]]
2019-06-11 09:15:14.255  INFO 96620 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Waiting for workers to finish.
2019-06-11 09:15:14.255  INFO 96620 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Successfully waited for workers to finish.
2019-06-11 09:15:14.257  INFO 96620 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Shutdown ignored - container is not active already
```

Comment: thanks but that event is never published, i extended the stacktrace above. i dont seem to be able to change the backoff policy via https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#_resilience_recovering_from_errors_and_broker_failures either, strange.

Comment: There's a bug in the direct MLC, the simple MLC publishes the event. Will fix. I am not sure what you mean by backoff policy. The 5 seconds is governed by the `recoveryInterval` or `recoveryBackOff`container properties.

Comment: just picked up your bugfix with spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE - works like a charme, thx!